# 3d Realtime Software Renderer Open Source

Tags: c++, 3d, renderer

Is there a good 3d realtime software renderer with features similar to OpenGL/DirectX? Something similar of what cairo or anti-grain do for 2d, but in 3d.

I actually just know Mesa witch has a software OpenGL implementation , and Coco3d.

It should be open source :)

Comment: I'm looking for a software renderer (like the OGL sample implementatio), not for a 3d library or scene graph that wraps OpenGL/DirectX . Something like coco3d!

Comment: there isn't anything that has all the features of OpenGL than the SGI reference sample!

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80807/pure-opengl-software-rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a pixel rendering engine why not have look at the [DOOM rendering engine](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Doom_rendering_engine) sources.

Another smaller and more standard API/OpenGL implementation called [TinyGL](http://fabrice.bellard.free.fr/TinyGL/) could be something to look at too.

Comment: This is far too specialized to match a requirement for a "OpenGL"-like rendering API, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look into [Orge 3D engine](http://www.ogre3d.org/) assuming you want an abstraction from the raw GL to something that already has a lot of the key features. It's open source too.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg) has grown to be pretty competent and widely used.

Answer (score 2):

Technically [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) is just a standard, but there are [OSS implementations](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample) available for download. I'm not sure you want a reference OGL driver though.

For 3d libraries, there are loads. [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net), [CrystalSpace](http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Main_Page), [Ogre3d](http://www.ogre3d.org/), to name just 3 off Sourceforge's trove list.

Answer (score 0):

The only major open source real-time software renderer besides Mesa I know of is the [Quake I engine](http://www.idsoftware.com/business/techdownloads/). However, it's not up to par with current OpenGL or Direct3D capabilities.

If you can do without the source code, you could have a look at the [Microsoft WARP10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285359.aspx) renderer. It's a high performance implementation of Direct3D 10 on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Coin](http://coin3d.org/lib/about_coin3d/coin3d-overview), an implementation of OpenInventor maintained by the company I'm employed by. It's licensed under a dual licensing model - GPL for free/opensource software. It's being actively developed and uses OpenGL to do rendering. It works on "all" platforms and can be easily integrated with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

For standalone alternatives to OpenGL / Direct3D i would look at

- Open source implementation of openGl : **[Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/)**
- **[Gallium3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium3D)**
- an implemantation of the the openRT specification: **[directViz](http://www.vsg3d.com/vsg_prod_openinventor_directviz.php)**
- some reasearch to implement realtime RenderMan : **[RenderMan for realtime](http://www.bestdamnpodcastever.com/millerblog/?p=55)**  and the **[progress](http://www.bestdamnpodcastever.com/millerblog/?cat=15)**

Answer (score -2):

OpenGL is open source, and should fall back to software rendering in the absense of 3D hardware on the system, provided that all the proper libraries are installed.

Comment: The "open" in OpenGL refers to the specification which is available at no cost. OpenGL itself is not a software, so there's no source code. In fact, the major OpenGL implementations by NVIDIA and AMD are closed source. The software rendering fall-back is a feature of your operating system, it's not mandated by the specification.